# How to retrieve data from db and display it in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having this code shown below but when it is running it's always gives an error saying
Message: Undefined variable: result why is it giving that error i can't figure it out ,Can anyone give me a solution please?

myads_model.php

```
<?php
    class Myads_model extends CI_Model
    {

        public function __construct()
    {

        $this->load->database();

    }

        public function getmyads( $SESSION['$email'] )
        {
            $this->db->select('Vehicleid,Image1,Brand,Model,Modelyear,
                               VehicleCondition,Mileage,BodyType,Transmission,
                               Fueltype,EngineCapacity,Price,Negotiable,
                               Description,Phone,Email');
            //$this->db->from('vehicle');
            $this->db->where('Email',$SESSION['$email']);
            $query=$this->db->get('vehicle');
            return $result=$query->result();
        }

    }

    ?>
```

myads_ctrl.php

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
*
*/
class Myads_ctrl extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();


    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data=array();
        $this->load->model('myads_model');

        $this->data['result']=$this->myads_model->getmyads($_SESSION['email']);
        $this->load->view('pages/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/myads_view', $this->data);
        $this->load->view('pages/templates/footer');
    }

}
?>
```

myads_view.php

#### My Ads

```
<?php $image=$post->Image1;
      $vehicleid=$post->Vehicleid;
echo '<img src="http://localhost/ci/images/' . $image . '" style="width:200px; height:150px;"/>';?>



<?php echo $post->Brand . " " . $post->Model . " " . $post->Modelyear;?>


<b>BRAND: <?php echo $post->Brand;?></b>
<b>MODEL : </b><?php echo $post->Model;?>
<b>MODEL YEAR : </b><?php echo $post->Modelyear;?>
<b>CONDITION : </b>
<?php echo $post->VehicleCondition;?>


<b>MILEAGE : </b><?php echo $post->Mileage;?>KM
<b>TRANSMISSION: </b><?php echo $post->Transmission;?>
<b>FUEL TYPE: </b><?php echo $post->Fueltype;?>


<b>Rs. </b><?php echo $post->Price;?>
<a href="<?php echo 'adpreview_ctrl/getad_preview/'.$vehicleid?>"><input type="button" value="View" class="btn-primary"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model do not name parameter as `$SESSION['$email']`, instead do `$email`. And change your select statement in the model to:

```
    public function getmyads( $email )
    {
      $this->db->select('your fields here');
      $this->db->from('vehicle');
      $this->db->where('Email', $email);

      $query = $this->db->get();
      $result = $query->result();
      return $result->num_rows() > 0 ? $result->result_array() : false;
    }
```

In your controller:

```
$this->data['result']=$this->myads_model->getmyads($_SESSION['email']);   
$this->load->view('pages/templates/header');
$this->load->view('pages/myads_view', $this->data);
$this->load->view('pages/templates/footer');
```

And in your view you should be able to access your result like:

```
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of var_dump($result) here

Comment: var_dump of $result will show you what was returned from model, either false or results

Comment: is it same as using foreach loop to iterate through each key,value pair

Comment: Yes you are right, var_dump is only for debugging purpose. This is only to clearly show if you have correct results or no results (false). There is no point to iterate through array if it's empty or does not exists. Your questions says "Undefined variable: result why is it giving that error i can't figure it out" so var_dump will show you if your database is returning any results or not.

Comment: ok i'll follow your advise , But still it hasn't solved. Can i know what does this lines means   $result->num_rows() > 0 ? $result->result_array() : false; in model

Comment: Can you please post result of var_dump($result); ? Basically $result->num_rows() > 0 ? $result->result_array() : false; is a simple if statement. This translates to: If there are records found in database return them, if not return false.

Comment: It prints only this                                                              var_dump($result);

Comment: Can anyone give me a solution please i'm troubling with this question for two days now :-(